# Expand Firestore search

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I need to somehow search an additional property in a document.

I have this reference that gets documents based on `name_lowercase` but I need to search the `symbol` property as well.

```
const dbRef = db.collection("content")
        .where('name_lowercase', '>=', searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        .where('name_lowercase', '<=', searchTerm.toLowerCase() + '~');
```

So I would need something like this also.

```
const dbRef = db.collection("content")
        .where('symbol', '>=', searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        .where('symbol', '<=', searchTerm.toLowerCase() + '~');
```

Should I just do a promise all and display the results? Or is there a better way?

Comment: According to my knowledge, you have to make multiple queries and fetch the objects and then take their intersection or union or whatever you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to perform range queries across multiple field with Firestore. From its documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

So you can either let the database perform the query on one field, and perform the rest of the filter in your application code, or you can integrate a separate solution for such text searches, for example as shown in the Firebase documentation on [full-text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).